# Are Raynox magnifiers compatible with Canon macro lenses?

Tags: lens, canon, macro, raynox

Are Raynox magnifiers (125, 250, 5320) compatible with Canon 100mm f/2.8L? In particular, are they going to be compatible with the Canon Macro Twin Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the thread size of the magnifier and the lens match, there will be no 'compatibility' issues - it's just a screw thread after all.

The flash is a different matter however. If the magnifier is a straightforward screw on type you shouldn't have a problem, but if clips on you may face difficulties.

Personally I wouldn't use a magnifier filter in any case: I would use extension tubes.